# Prototype & Javascript Conflict with ILightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I have a lightbox that I'm trying to use and it's not been working in our Magento store. I finally traced the issue back to Prototype -- once I remove Prototype, it works of course. So, other than putting jQuery into no-conflict mode (which I've done), or removing Prototype from Magento (which I can't), I'm wondering what can be done.

The URL for the demo is [here](http://staging.autopartsnetwork.com/test.html).

Thanks!

Comment: why would you expect different solution than `noConflict`, is what it is intended for. If it's not working, show how you are implementing it

Comment: That makes sense.. thank you. I have it implemented as such:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://staging.autopartsnetwork.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
 </script>

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I removed the tag `prototype` because prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 isn't the same as as prototypejs and it has nothing to do with this particular question. As for your question: try using the console in Chrome or Firefox and see if you have any errors. In Chrome press F12 and firefox press control + shift + k.

Comment: Hey there, HMR. No problem at all -- and thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since whole problem stems from `prototype.js` controlling `$` alias, don't use `$` to initalize `noConflict` use `jQuery`

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

A simple wrapper you can use to allow using `$` in your jQuery code is:

```
(function($){
    /* $ is jQuery inside this wrapper*/
    $(function(){
         $('#someDiv').doSomething()
     })

 })(jQuery);
```

There are sevral other methods of implementation

**[jQuery.noConflict() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**